# Function with 2 variables

Tags: calculus

We have the next function $z=x^2y-y^2x$
and we know that: $x=p\cos(a), y=p\sin(a)$.
Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial p}$ and  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}$.

In my opinion, at first we should find $z(\cos(a),p\sin(a))$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Given $z=x^2y-y^2x$ and $x=p \cos a$, $y=p \sin a$, \begin{align}z&=(p \cos a)^2 (p \sin a)-(p \sin a)^2(p\cos a)\\&= p^3 (\cos^2 a \sin a-\sin^2 a \cos a) \end{align}

Can you now find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial p}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}$?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain rule to solve it. For example:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial p} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial p}$